# Is $ f(z) = z^{3/2} $ holomorphic at $ z= 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Consider $f:  \mathbb{C} 
 \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $, where $f(z) = z^{3/2} $. Now evaluating derivative at $0$ using $$\lim_{h\to 0} (f(0+h)- f(0))/h$$, we get $f'(0)=0$. So $f$ is infinitely differentiable at $0$. However $f''(0)$ doesn't exist at 0 since $f''(z) = 3/4 (z^{-1/2})$.

How's that possible?

Comment: How are you defining $z^{3/2}$?

Comment: You need to make a branch cut in order to define $z^{3/2}$ in a neighborhood of $0$ -- so while the function is differentiable _at_ 0, it will not be so _in a neighborhood of_ 0.